# Count rows for every day between two date columns SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, asp.net-core, group-by

I have a table 'events' :

```
id | name | date_start | date_end
---+------+------------+------------
1  | aaa  | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03
2  | bbb  | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-05
```

And I want to count rows for every day between `date_start` and `date_end` from that table, for example:

- from the first row I want result looks like this:

```
date       | count
-----------+-------
2020-01-01 | 1
2020-01-02 | 1
2020-01-03 | 1
```

- from the second row:

```
date       | count
---------------------
2020-01-02 | 1
2020-01-03 | 1
2020-01-04 | 1
2020-01-05 | 1
```

So the final result should look like this:

```
date       | count
-----------+-------
2020-01-01 | 1
2020-01-02 | 2
2020-01-03 | 2
2020-01-04 | 1
2020-01-05 | 1
```

Is it possible to do with sql or should I calculate it on server? That table will have thousand of rows so I dont want to load all of them when I need only that result.

Using ASP.NET Core 3.1 with SQL Server.

Comment: What have you tried. Have you had a look at the `COUNT` function? Why do you feel that *wouldn't* work for what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A recursive CTE is convenient here (if you don't have a numbers table or a calendar table on-hand).

```
with cte as (
      select id, name, date_start, date_end
      from t
      union all
      select id, name, dateadd(day, 1, date_start), date_end
      from t
      where date_start < date_end
     )
select date_start as date, count(*)
from cte
group by date_start
order by date_start;
```

If any of the periods are longer than 100 days, you need to add `option (maxrecursion)` to the query.

Comment: Thanks thats exactly what I need

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive `cte` :

```
with cte as (
   select t.date_start, t.date_end
   from table t
   union all
   select dateadd(day, 1, date_start), date_end
   from cte c
   where c.date_start < c.date_end
)
select date_start, count(*) as cnt
from cte c
group by date_start
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with calendar talbe. See sample data below and the query:

```
declare @tbl table (id int, name varchar(20), date_start date, date_end date)
insert into @tbl values
( 1  , 'aaa'  , '2020-01-01' , '2020-01-03'),
( 2  , 'bbb'  , '2020-01-02' , '2020-01-05');
-- set boundaries for calendar
declare @startDate date, @endDate date;
select @startDate = min(date_start), @endDate = max(date_end) from @tbl;

;with calendar as (
    select @startDate dates
    union all
    select dateadd(day, 1, dates) from calendar
    where dates < @endDate
)
select c.dates, count(*) from calendar c
join @tbl t on c.dates between t.date_start and t.date_end
group by c.dates
```